# The result of the gsub function gets distorted. Any idea why?

Tags: r, gsub

I get distorted output when I try to replace the question mark symbol by the digit zero. Given below my code.

```
x <- c(2,3,"m","M","b","?")
x1 <- gsub("m|M","6",x)
x1
#[1] "2" "3" "6" "6" "b" "?"
x1 <- gsub("?","0",x)
x1
#[1] "020" "030" "0m0" "0M0" "0b0" "0?0"
```

Anybody have any idea why this happens? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `gsub("\\?","0",x)` You need to escape the `?` as it is a special character.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` is a metacharacter, we need to escape ("\?") or place it inside square brackets

```
gsub("[?]", "0", x1)
```

Or use `fixed = TRUE`

```
gsub("?", "0", x1, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!
Any idea what should we do if want to replace null character with zero?

Comment: I checked it out. Any solution for the empty element ("") replacement?

Comment: @PaulDavis  I couldn't find the empty element in your example\